# Improving Game EventSystem

Tags: c#, performance, unity3d

There is a Unity `EventManager` class from Unity [tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events-creating-simple-messaging-system) that allows events to be registered, unregistered and invoked. The bad side of that `EventManager` code is that it uses [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) which is slow and it does not take parameter.

I decided to rewrite it with `Action` from C# instead of Unity's [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) and also added support for parameter. Below is the new `EventManager` I modified that uses `Action` and it also allows any amount of parameter to be passed to the event.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EventManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Dictionary<string, Action<EventParam>> eventDictionary;

    private static EventManager eventManager;

    public static EventManager instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (!eventManager)
            {
                eventManager = FindObjectOfType(typeof(EventManager)) as EventManager;

                if (!eventManager)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("There needs to be one active EventManger script on a GameObject in your scene.");
                }
                else
                {
                    eventManager.Init();
                }
            }
            return eventManager;
        }
    }

    void Init()
    {
        if (eventDictionary == null)
        {
            eventDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Action<EventParam>>();
        }
    }

    public static void StartListening(string eventName, Action<EventParam> listener)
    {
        Action<EventParam> thisEvent;
        if (instance.eventDictionary.TryGetValue(eventName, out thisEvent))
        {
            //Add more event to the existing one
            thisEvent += listener;

            //Update the Dictionary
            instance.eventDictionary[eventName] = thisEvent;
        }
        else
        {
            //Add event to the Dictionary for the first time
            thisEvent += listener;
            instance.eventDictionary.Add(eventName, thisEvent);
        }
    }

    public static void StopListening(string eventName, Action<EventParam> listener)
    {
        if (eventManager == null) return;
        Action<EventParam> thisEvent;
        if (instance.eventDictionary.TryGetValue(eventName, out thisEvent))
        {
            //Remove event from the existing one
            thisEvent -= listener;

            //Update the Dictionary
            instance.eventDictionary[eventName] = thisEvent;
        }
    }

    public static void TriggerEvent(string eventName, EventParam eventParam)
    {
        Action<EventParam> thisEvent = null;
        if (instance.eventDictionary.TryGetValue(eventName, out thisEvent))
        {
            thisEvent.Invoke(eventParam);
            // OR USE  instance.eventDictionary[eventName](eventParam);
        }
    }
}

//Re-usable structure/ Can be a class to. Add all parameters you need inside it
public struct EventParam
{
    public string param1;
    public int param2;
    public float param3;
    public bool param4;
}
```

**USAGE**:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Action<EventParam> someListener1;
    private Action<EventParam> someListener2;
    private Action<EventParam> someListener3;

    void Awake()
    {
        someListener1 = new Action<EventParam>(SomeFunction);
        someListener2 = new Action<EventParam>(SomeOtherFunction);
        someListener3 = new Action<EventParam>(SomeThirdFunction);

        StartCoroutine(invokeTest());
    }

    IEnumerator invokeTest()
    {
        WaitForSeconds waitTime = new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        //Create parameter to pass to the event
        EventParam eventParam = new EventParam();
        eventParam.param1 = "Hello";
        eventParam.param2 = 99;
        eventParam.param3 = 43.4f;
        eventParam.param4 = true;

        while (true)
        {
            yield return waitTime;
            EventManager.TriggerEvent("test", eventParam);
            yield return waitTime;
            EventManager.TriggerEvent("Spawn", eventParam);
            yield return waitTime;
            EventManager.TriggerEvent("Destroy", eventParam);
        }
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        //Register With Action variable
        EventManager.StartListening("test", someListener1);
        EventManager.StartListening("Spawn", someListener2);
        EventManager.StartListening("Destroy", someListener3);

        //OR Register Directly to function
        EventManager.StartListening("test", SomeFunction);
        EventManager.StartListening("Spawn", SomeOtherFunction);
        EventManager.StartListening("Destroy", SomeThirdFunction);
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        //Un-Register With Action variable
        EventManager.StopListening("test", someListener1);
        EventManager.StopListening("Spawn", someListener2);
        EventManager.StopListening("Destroy", someListener3);

        //OR Un-Register Directly to function
        EventManager.StopListening("test", SomeFunction);
        EventManager.StopListening("Spawn", SomeOtherFunction);
        EventManager.StopListening("Destroy", SomeThirdFunction);
    }

    void SomeFunction(EventParam eventParam)
    {
        Debug.Log("Some Function was called!");
    }

    void SomeOtherFunction(EventParam eventParam)
    {
        Debug.Log("Some Other Function was called!");
    }

    void SomeThirdFunction(EventParam eventParam)
    {
        Debug.Log("Some Third Function was called!");
    }
}
```

---

It's working fine.I know I can use the [`params`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) keyword to receive multiple arguments but I am trying to avoid using the [`params`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) keyword as it also creates garbage during run-time so I used a `struct` called "`EventParam`" to hold and pass all my parameters.

I want to know if there is anything to improve in this script and if there is any other *better* way to handle parameter other than the current way I am currently doing it.

Comment: Note that UnityEvent can be parameterized to take parameters via UnityEvent<ParameterTypeA, ParameterTypeB> etc.

Comment: @EdMarty Yes I know but that doesn't matter since part of the improvement was getting ride of `UnityEvent` and using `Action`. I don't use `UnityEvent`

Comment: Yeah,I'm not suggesting you switch back to use it. I'm only mentioning it because at the beginning of your question you say that it's not parameterizable.

Comment: @EdMarty I meant that the EventManager from that tutorial does not take parameter not the UnityEvent. Bad phrasing I guess.

Answer (score 3):

1. Why do you have both: static methods and static instance? You should either remove the `instance` property (as if you had a "static" class, just make `eventDictionary` static), or keep it, but make methods non-static (singleton (anti-)pattern).
2. I'm pretty sure this line should throw `NullReferenceException`.

   > ```
   > //Add event to the Dictionary for the first time
   > thisEvent += listener;
   > ```

   If `thisEvent` was not found in a dictionary, it should be `null` at this point.
3. This does not look reusable to me:

   > ```
   > //Re-usable structure/ Can be a class to. Add all parameters you need inside it
   > public struct EventParam
   > {
   >     public string param1;
   >     public int param2;
   >     public float param3;
   >     public bool param4;
   > }
   > ```

   The meaning of those fields is extremely unclear, and the suggestion to "add all parameters you need" sounds like a bad idea. What if two events need different sets of parameters? What if one of them needs two floats? How will this architecture evolve then? I see two ways to make this class reusable.

   - One is to use weakly typed parameters, so instead of passing `EventParam` you pass `object` and trust that event handlers will do the cast correctly. Very usafe, but easy to implement.
   - A much better approach is to use generic methods and instead of `EventParam` use generic argument as parameter. It is harder to implement properly though.

Comment: **1.** I wanted to have only one instance of `EventManager`. It is a component that is supposed to be attached to a GameObject so I can't make that class  `static` because then inheriting from `MonoBehaviour` would be useless since it can't be attached to a GameObject. With your comment, I now think that `instance` variable should changed to a `private` instead of `public` since it's not being used outside of that class.   - **2** I don't understand what you mean. Could you please rephrase that or add more info?

Comment: **3.** The `EventParam` is just a wrapper for parameters. The user is supposed to add/remove variables they want to pass inside the struct. The four variables inside it are just used for test. I can't use `object` for that since it creates garbage due to boxing/unboxing of types. I don't think you can use generics for this without using reflection. If you think otherwise, it would be awesome to provide an example. My biggest goal here is performance not readability and I have avoided stuff like using `object` for params or using reflection.

Comment: 1. That's why I've put "static" in quotes. I see that you need inheritance, but it does not change the fact that you can still make all the methods static an remove the `instance` property. 2. I mean that this line will throw exception. I do not know how to say it differently. :) 3. You do not need reflection, but you do need a strong knowledge of C#. Here is a standalnoe implementation form Prism, for example: https://github.com/tngraf/Prism.EventAggregator .

Comment: P.S. You should not sacrifice readability in favor of some abstract performance gains, unless you have a specific goal in mind. Write a solid readable code, then test its performance against your concrete goals. Only then, if it is "too slow", you should start optimizing it. Don't jump to conclusions, assuming that it *will* be to slow. In most cases - it simply won't be the case.

Comment: You can ensure to have only one instance by using the tipp to make it a singleton and let unity create it when needed. Like this:
 `private static EventManager eventManager = null;
 public static EventManager instance{
  get {
   if (eventManager == null) {
    GameObject EventManagerGO = new GameObject ("EventManager");
    eventManager = EventManagerGO.AddComponent<EventManager> ();
    eventManager.Init ();
   }
   return eventManager;
  }
  protected set { }
 }`

Answer (score 1):

Just an Information, which helps with either the unity tutorial EventManager or the one posted above:

Use the `StartListening` call in `Awake()` and the `StopListening` in `~YourClass()` to have disabled GameObjects listen to events.

(This is an answer not a comment, because I cannot post comments yet.)

Comment: Yes, I know about this. Forget about the Test script. What I really want to improve is the `EventManager` class itself.

Answer (score -2):

I am doing a similar thing, but I created an IParamEvent. I then create a class for each event and inherit from IParamEvent.

```
public interface IEventParam
{   
    string Name { get; set; }
}
class CarSpeedParam : IEventParam
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you show how to implement this pattern in the OP's code?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but in what way is this an improvement on the code that OP presented? You're not gaining very much by inheriting a `Name` property for every custom event...

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].